# Equals method in objects

Tags: java, object, equals

This is my code:

```
Object a = "1234";
Object b = new Integer("1234");
```

I know that `==` means references and `equals()` means contains.

Now why `a.equals(b)` is false?

Each of them has the same value.

Comment: One is a `String`, the other is an `Integer`... They cannot be equal

Comment: you are comparing String value with Integer value

Comment: Because java ain't javascript

Comment: i don't under stnad the downvotes. the content of both object IS equal... i would say the question is valid.

Comment: No, the content is not equal. `a` contains a String of value "1234", `b` contains an Integer of value 1234. Using the String-parameter constructor of Integer (which just parses the String to an int) does not make an Integer a String.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because both are from different classes. `a` is from `String` class, and `b` is from `Integer` class. So, it will return `false` without going further and checking the content of the instances.

Even though, you have declared both instances with `Object` reference, but, in the run time, when you call `.equals()` method, they will delegated to their actual classes of the instances.

For example if you take `String` class `equals()` method, it will be like

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
           char v1[] = value;
           char v2[] = anotherString.value;
           int i = offset;
           int j = anotherString.offset;
           while (n-- != 0) {
            if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
            return false;
           }
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, if you passed an instance of another class, it will return `false`.

Answer (score 5):

Your `a` is an `Object` container, containing a `String` object, while your `b` is an `Object` container, containing an `Integer` object.

When you call `equals()` on `a`, it does `String.equals()`, which finds out that your `String` just isn't equal to an `Integer` and no amount of auto-boxing and -unboxing can make it so.

Answer (score 1):

As [Kugathasan Abimaran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908158/equals-method-in-objects/21908169#21908169) already gave an explanation I will just add this small code with which you can see for yourself:

```
System.out.println(a + " might look like " + b + " but " + a.getClass() + " does not equal " + b.getClass());
```

Which will result in:

> 1234 might look like 1234 but class java.lang.String does not equal class java.lang.Integer